# Can OpenVPN create the default route if it doesn't exist?

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn, network-namespaces

### Note

This question was originally asked about OpenVPN not setting a default gateway if one did not already exist even if you specify `--redirect-gateway local` or `--redirect-gateway def1`. [As of 2.4.1](https://www.mail-archive.com/openvpn-devel@lists.sourceforge.net/msg13905.html), OpenVPN *does* set a default gateway with this option whether or not one exists already, so it's obsolete if you're using that version.

Note that the version of OpenVPN in Ubuntu Zesty is 2.4.0, and doesn't have this change. But the version from Artful installs without issue on Zesty.

---

I have created a network namespace under Ubuntu 14.04.5, with a plan to run a VPN inside that (using OpenVPN 2.3.2 and a config file). The idea is that no traffic can be routed out of the namespace until the VPN is running.

I've implemented this by not creating a default route, and instead whitelisting the VPN server IP address. So my routing table looks like:

```
# ip netns exec testns ip route add A.B.C.D/32 via 10.200.200.1 dev veth1
# ip netns exec testns ip route show
10.200.200.0/24 dev veth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.200.200.2 
A.B.C.D via 10.200.200.1 dev veth1
```

Note that `10.200.200.1` is the address of `veth0`, the other end of the virtual interface `veth1` (`10.200.200.2`). I've confirmed that my `iptables` rules and IP forwarding in the root namespace works to get traffic in and out of the `testns` namespace when there's a route for it. `A.B.C.D` is the VPN server address.

To bring the VPN up, I run `ip netns exec testns openvpn abcd.ovpn`. This config file contains a `pull` directive, and the `push`ed config from the server contains:

```
PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1,dhcp-option[...]
```

But then a little later, I see:

```
NOTE: unable to redirect default gateway -- Cannot read current default gateway from system
```

And, accordingly, there is no default route set up in my `testns` namespace.

According to the manual, `redirect-gateway def1` *doesn't* try to replace the default route, it just creates two new ones `0.0.0.0/1` and `128.0.0.0/1`. How does not having a default route prevent these from being created? And how can I get OpenVPN to automatically route all traffic through the VPN when a default route doesn't initially exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> According to the manual, redirect-gateway def1 doesn't try to replace the default route, it just creates two new ones 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1. How does not having a default route prevent these from being created?

If OpenVPN were only to override the default gateway it would no longer be able to get to its peer endpoint via that original gateway. So what it does first is to look at the default gateway and set an explicit host route for its peer endpoint via that gateway.

The man page for OpenVPN is quite explicit about this:

> **--redirect-gateway flags...**
>
> Automatically execute routing commands to cause all outgoing IP
>   traffic  to  be redirected over the VPN.  This is a client-side
>   option.
>
> This option performs three steps:
>
> (1)  Create  a static route for the --remote address which forwards to
>   the pre-existing default gateway.  This is done so that (3) will not
>   create  a  routing loop.
>
> (2) Delete the default gateway route.
>
> (3)  Set the new default gateway to be the VPN endpoint address
>   (derived either from --route-gateway or the second parameter to
>   --ifconfig when  --dev  tun  is specified).
>
> When  the  tunnel is torn down, all of the above steps are reversed so
>   that the original default route is restored.

You then ask

> how can I get OpenVPN to automatically route all traffic through the VPN when a default route doesn't initially exist?

A route must exist (somewhere) for the OpenVPN client to get to its peer endpoint (i.e. the server). So whatever that route is, you will need to implement the three tasks described above in a `--up` script. You'll need to  write this script, of course.

Comment: *A route must exist (somewhere) for the OpenVPN client to get to its peer endpoint (i.e. the server).* - Yep, I set a single route that points to the server  `ip route add A.B.C.D/32 via 10.200.200.1 dev veth1`, as a kind of off-by-default kill switch.

Comment: @detly n that case all you should need is step (3) then.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess what I was asking was whether there's a way to tell OpenVPN to do this automatically rather than having to write a script myself. But if there's not, there's not, I'll write a script. I think OpenVPN exports some useful env vars for this purpose too.

Comment: The script should only be one or two lines - basically a pair of `route add` lines in the manner of the ones that OpenVPN would add

Comment: For the record, my script is basically `ip route add default via $5 dev $1`. `$5` is the `ifconfig_remote_ip` arg and `$1` is the `tun_dev` arg.

Answer (score 1):

Two work around options:

- Set a fake default gateway (eg 127.0.0.1) and allow OpenVPN to overwrite it.
- Use a post run script to set the gateway using ip route